# Why given function is not continuous at $x=0$ for $n=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x):=x^n$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x):=0$ for $x \lt 0$. For which values of $n$ is $f^{'} $ continuous at 0? For which values of $n$ $f^{'}$ is differentiable at $0$?

I was trying to solve this and we can see that $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$ for $n=1$,

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x \lt 0 \end{cases} $$

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = 0 \hspace{5mm}  \bigg{|} \hspace{5mm} \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x) = 0 $$

But answer in the book says **$f^{'}$ is continuous for $n \geq 2$ and differentiable $n \geq 3$**

Would you please help me with this I also tried to check for $n=2,3 ...$ but as we see closer and closer to 0 given $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable for all values of $n$. I don't know why I am thinking like this, but please correct me I am learning Real Analysis these days.

Comment: The question is about the continuity of $f'$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh yeah! Now I got where I was making mistake, Thank you very much.